# Windows 10 does not boot (Maybe isn't considered as OS?)

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, windows-10, grub

I have a problem with booting Windows 10.
I use Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04 and first I instantly got back to GRUB when selecting Windows 10 then I booted from Windows 10 installer media and ran following commands:

```
bootrec.exe/fixmbr
bootrec.exe/fixboot
bootrec.exe/scanos
bootrec.exe/rebuildbcd
```

I reinstalled GRUB and now I don't get back into GRUB after selecting Windows 10 but I get a blackscreen showing _ and Windows does still not boot.

After I executed bootrec.exe/scanos I got the following message:

The searching after Windows-installations was successful. Number of identified installations: 1 [1] C:\Windows.old\Windows (sorry for bad translation)

Notice: I have updatet from Windows 7 to Windows 10

For me it looks like Windows does not consider the current OS but I can't think of anything that could help.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can try using the free EasyRE repair CD for Windows 10: http://neosmart.net/easyre/ - it's a bootable CD so you might have some luck with it. But if you don't have an OS in C:\ and only in C:\Windows\ that probably means setup never finished.

Comment: Well I already used Windows 10 a few days and I can't remember what happend that it doesn't boot any longer. But the system worked and should work

Comment: Try the CD, then.

Comment: any danger to lose data?

Comment: No, not really.

Comment: @Mahmoud well EasyRE is a really nice tool and I think I'll keep it, but unfortunately I get the following error: 'The selected partition does not contain a valid Windows Installation. You've either selected a data drive, or the volume has been formatted and cannot be repaired.'

Comment: To me your main problem is that Bootrec did not find your new Windows 10 installation (it found the semi-disabled Windows 7; do not try to boot from it directly, it won't work: you need to restore it to working state by using Windows 10 _revert to Windows 7_ option.) I guess you can recreate manually the BCD entry to boot Windows 10, but it will probably fail down the line with something missing...

Comment: @AntoineL will it uninstall Windows 10 then? or I don't understand what or how to do what you suggest

Comment: I do not believe you will be allowed to smoothly uninstall Windows 10 (or more exactly, allowed to restore the previous Seven) if you are not allowed to boot into it. I do not know how to guide you since there is a lot of informations I cannot decide, like if you have backups (_exports_) of the BCD, if running UEFI, where is the ["system"](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/boot-and-system-volumes.html) partition,...

Comment: I don't have any exports of the BCD (if I had to do them manually) and I use a BIOS based system so Windows is placed in the first partition and GRUB in the Ubuntu partition

Comment: @PhileReinhardt Windows and EasyRE are both telling you that Windows is no longer installed to C:\

Comment: yes I know... but it is there.. so why they are telling me that? Or is it pointless to search a solution and should I format the partition and reinstall Windows?

Comment: Quickly check that your first partition, is active, is formatted as NTFS, has a file `/BOOTMGR`, that there is a `/Boot` directory, with files named `BCD*`. All of this should be the result from running `bootrec` as described above; most are hidden, so from Windows you need to use `dir/a`.

Then check there is also a directory `\Windows`, within it `System32`, within it files `winload.exe`, `winresume.exe`, `ntoskrnl.exe`, `hal.dll`, and a `Config` directory with a file `SYSTEM` within it; if everything is there, my last idea is a problem with the `*.mui` files not in place...

Comment: all of the files you mentioned are in their directory

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/655011/windows-10-upgrade-kills-grub-and-boot-repair-doesnt-help): According to what Nicholas said:

> I just had to run this in windows: bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path
> \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi Grub appears fine on boot and I can boot into
> Ubuntu and Win10 fine.

this solved my problem.

Comment: but in this case it is a different problem. Do you really think it also solves my problem?
And if it does.. I don't use UEFI, what would be the path for a BIOS system?

Comment: as u siad `The searching after Windows-installations was successful. Number of identified installations: 1 [1] C:\Windows.old\Windows (sorry for bad translation)` change it to C:\Windows it tries to search for the Windows in windows.old

Comment: just that I don't make any mistakes
in my case it would be bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path C:\Windows
as normal command? or do I have to replace anything?
sorry but normally I don't work with Windows commands

Comment: yeah that is right

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a good idea to look here (http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/).
Boot into Ubuntu live and try to install grub on all drives `Place Grub in all disks`. and there is a great chance that it should fix booting problems (since you are overwriting any boot sectors that existed and in other words you are removing them)
Well I decided to put some portion of that link here:

1. Boot into Ubuntu Live CD and put these lines into terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
boot-repair
```

2. Then Grub Boot Repair GUI is installed.
   [image]
   [image]

Well, I think the second option in first image `Create a Bootinfo summary (to get help by email or forum)` is a good choice for making it clear what really happened to your computer! You can post what it says there here to inform us.

Hope this helps.

Comment: you mean I shall install GRUB in the Ubuntu and Windows partition? Because later on it is asked again

Comment: yeah, both. BTW i encourage you to create a backup of your important data using ubuntu live cd. At least you would have the option to reinstall Windows and ubuntu again.

Comment: I don't think there is a problem with GRUB or chainloading. I think the problem is that Windows itself doesn't consider a bootable OS

Answer (score 0):

On my netbook I have dual-boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 15.4

**BCDedit** is the best to make a bootable menu for the MBR Windows boot.

## **Grub Customizer** installed in Ubuntu to make a boot menu for GRUB.

GRUB in my case is placed in the Linux ext4 partition, while the MBR is original Windows. The two menus are completely chained. As soon as I get home I can write more details, if this will be of any interest to you.